# Can not convert with cvMerge,DFT

Tags: opencv, merge, dft

I am trying to make the dft of one single channeled image, and as cvDft is expecting complex values, I was adviced to merge the original image with another image with all 0's so this last one will be considered as imaginary part.

My problem comes when using cvmerge function,

```
Mat tmp = imread(filename,0);

if( tmp.empty() )
    {cout << "Usage: dft <image_name>" << endl;
    return -1;}
Mat Result(tmp.rows,tmp.cols,CV_64F,2);
Mat tmp1(tmp.rows,tmp.cols,CV_64F, 0);
Mat image(tmp.rows,tmp.cols,CV_64F,2);
cvMerge(tmp,tmp1,image);`
```

It gives me the next error: can not convert cvMAt to cvArr

Anyone could help me? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1) it seems like you're mixing up 2 different styles of opencv code
`cv::Mat` (- Mat) is a c++ class from the new version of opencv, `cvMerge` is a c function from the old version of opencv.

instead of using `cvmerge` use [merge](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_operations_on_arrays.html#cv-merge)

2) you're trying to merge a matrix (`tmp`) of type `CV_8U` (probably) with a `CV_64F`
   use [convertTo](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_basic_structures.html#cv-mat-convertto) to get tmp as CV_64F

3) why is your `Result` & `image` mats (the destination mat) are initializes to `cv::Scalar(2)`? i think you're misusing the constractor parameters. see [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_basic_structures.html#cv-mat-mat) for more info.

4) you're `image` mat is a single channel mat and you wanted it as a 2 channel mat (as mentioned in the question), change the declaration to

```
Mat image(tmp.rows,tmp.cols,CV_64FC2);
```

Comment: Ok, many thanks, i'm going to try, I keep you updated. Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome, enjoy. if the answer solved your problem, please accept the answer by clicking on the V sign under the answer votes score.